# Error : Unauthorized error happend: Full authentication is required to access this resource

Tags: javascript, spring, jwt

I am trying to implement a authentication using Spring Boot, JWT with Roles

I have the error:

> full authentication is required to access this resource

when send POST request to "http://localhost:8080/qeustions/delete/{question-id}"

```
export const DeleteAsk = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.delete(
      "http://localhost:8080/questions/delete/8",
      {
        // 서버측에서 유저아이디 받기
        userId: localStorage.getItem("userId"),
      },
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: localStorage.getItem("Token"), //authorization 값 전송
          dataType: "json",
        },
      }
    );
    return response;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};
```

This is my config file in spring

```
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {

   ....
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/users/signup").permitAll()       
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH, "/users/mypage/edit/**").hasRole("USER")  
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/users").permitAll()    
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/users/mypage/**").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN") 
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/users/**").hasRole("USER")  
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/questions/ask").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN") 
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH, "/questions/**").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/questions").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/guestions/**").permitAll()   
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/questions/delete/**").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")

                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/questions/**/answers").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH, "/questions/**/answers/**").hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN")
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/questions/**/answers/**").hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN")
                );

        return http.build();
    }
}
    ....

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedOriginPatterns(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.addExposedHeader("*");
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PATCH", "DELETE" , "OPTION"));  

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration); 
        return source;

    }
   ...
}
```

I try change headers